# Android assets not included in build

Tags: android, build, assets

I have an application that displays local html in a webview. The web page includes(quite a lot) local pdfs from the assets folder.

My problem is that not all the assets are included in the apk. I noticed if I remove the pdfs then all my assets will be included, but if I include the pdfs about half my assets are included.

I've spent about 3 hours on this and have no clue what to do

Edit:

This seems to be an issue with the newest build tools for Android L. I just tried a project that I built last week fine and it still didn't include all of my assets.

Comment: You might want to clarify this a bit. "remove" and "take out" are synonymous to me. Also, how big are the assets? Smallest/Largest file size, how many, total size?

Comment: Oh brainfart. I edited my original. The largest is about 1.2mb, the total size of the app is about 230mb

Comment: An apk can't be larger than 50MB. You'll either need an extension APK or download assets post-install from a CDN.

Comment: I've had my applications up to 200MB I believe

Comment: [Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Comment: @323go I don't think this Google Play specific restriction affects the build process in general.

Comment: @cygery Yeah, I didn't think the build process would be affected by it either, because last week I had the app up to 236mb.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect the additional details you've clarified in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to post an answer here in case anyone else runs into this.

Don't forget to update your ADT plugin. If that doesn't work you can just revert to the build tools-20